System doesn't start due to bad Superblock
I cannot boot anymore into my Xubuntu 22.04 Linux machine after I have shrunk the system partition of Xubuntu (since I had need space after it) from another Debian System with KDE Partition Manager.
The Xubuntu system partition is on SSD drive on an nvme partition (a windows is also on this drive).
I first have tried with fsck right in initramfs in the boot process but I get the same as with e2fsck
... superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
I guess its a superblock.
What could I do ... except installing a new system... ?
Any Chance when I backup and restore this partition in KDE Partition Manager after creating a new partition?
rolfi@rolf-vivobookasuslaptopx513eak513ea:~$ sudo e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/nvme0n1p9
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 7792136 blocks
The physical size of the device is 7401984 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort? yes

rolfi@rolf-vivobookasuslaptopx513eak513ea:~$ sudo e2fsck -p -f -v /dev/nvme0n1p9
/dev/nvme0n1p9: The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 7792136 blocks
The physical size of the device is 7401984 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!


/dev/nvme0n1p9: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
    (i.e., without -a or -p options)


From your install media (USB mem stick - selecting Try ubuntu) you can install and run 'testdisk' as per the following instructions. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-recover-partition-table-in-linux. It stands a good chance to fix things up to make it mountable and to extract the uncorrected bits of data and may fix it completely.

Thanks @david. The partition couldn't be repaired. But I was a fool, have written the results ... then the blue Windows Recovery screen appeared after reboot...  I wonder if the windows Recovery is able to recover the partition table only ?

After readinding this it was clear that I just need to take out the SSD drive.
https://superuser.com/questions/955525/where-is-the-uefi-boot-order-stored
Booted then from the Debian Live stick und could accsses the UEFI Firmware.
Now the Windows boot was in first position of boot order.
Then I reinserted the SSD but connected the livestick before switching on.
The blue PC Rescue Screen from Windows appears again.
I put Debian partition to the top in UEFI and it booted.
But the SSD is not displayed from filemangaer in Debian.
Now how to rescue the data from SSD Home partition.
